# Updating total using values from previous row - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that depends on the previous row’s values for its new total. We have discovered that a couple of years ago a value was incorrectly altered and has subsequently made all following values incorrect.  I have inherited a formula that uses the previous date to calculate but there appears to be dates missing in the table and at this point the formula stops. I would like to make the update use the previous row rather than the date. I have tried using LAG but had issues using it with an UPDATE.

This is an example of the type of data I am using

```
|  Date   |Value1|Value2|Value3|Total
--------------------------------
|20151112 |  2   |  2   |  3   | 20
```

I need to add Value1 + Value2 + Value3 * Previous Day Total. The answer to this will update the following row's total. As mentioned I need to use an UPDATE because there is existing data in the total, but it's currently incorrect.

The results I would like to achieve are in the Table below. Please be aware that dates are not sequential so I can't use date as a condition. An answer with LAG would be great.

```
|  Date   |Value1|Value2|Value3|Total
--------------------------------
|20151112 |  2   |  2   |  3   | 20
|20151114 |  2   |  3   |  1   | 140
|20151115 |  1   |  1   |  1   | 420
|20151117 |  1   |  3   |  1   | 2100
|20151119 |  2   |  1   |  3   | 12600
```

Example - for the 20151114 - 2 + 2 + 3 * 20 (Total from the previous row) = 140

Comment: Could you add some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Hi McNets. I have simplified my question and added sample data and the desired result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar once and had a good result from using a windowing function like below:

```
SELECT RunningTotal = History.Total + ISNULL((SUM(History.Total) OVER 
                    (PARTITION BY PartitionID 
                    ORDER BY History.EffectiveDate ASC, History.HistoryID ASC 
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)), 0)
FROM   History
ORDER BY History.EffectiveDate, History.HistoryID
```

This sums up all of the rows before the current row.

You can't update straight from that, but you could put it into a CTE or insert the data into a temp table and then update from one of those.

The performance of it isn't great, but for a one off script in a maintenance window it was good enough for us.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you must use a cursor due you need to store the previous calculated total.

Note I've added the previous `UniqueIdentifierCode` because one `FOR UPDATE` cursor requires a primary key.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Hist 
> (
>     UniqueIdentifierCode VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
>     EffectiveDate date, 
>     Value1 decimal(18,4), 
>     Value2 decimal(18,4),
>     Value3 decimal(18,4),
>     Total decimal(18,4)
> );
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Hist VALUES
> ('N01', '20151112', 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 20),
> ('N02', '20151114', 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0),
> ('N03', '20151115', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0),
> ('N04', '20151117', 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0),
> ('N05', '20151119', 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0);
>
> GO
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @NEW_TOTAL DECIMAL(18,4) = 0;
> DECLARE @FIRST BIT = 1;
>
> DECLARE @V1 DECIMAL(18,4),
>         @V2 DECIMAL(18,4),
>         @V3 DECIMAL(18,4),
>         @T DECIMAL(18,4);
>         
> DECLARE curHist CURSOR FOR
>     SELECT Value1,
>            Value2,
>            Value3,
>            Total
>     FROM   Hist
>     ORDER BY EffectiveDate
>     FOR UPDATE OF Total;
>     
>     
> OPEN curHist;
> FETCH NEXT FROM curHist INTO @V1, @V2, @V3, @T;
>
> WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
> BEGIN
>
>     IF @FIRST = 1
>     BEGIN
>         SET @NEW_TOTAL = (@V1 + @V2 + @V3) * @T;
>     END
>     ELSE
>     BEGIN
>         UPDATE Hist
>         SET    Total = @NEW_TOTAL
>         WHERE  CURRENT OF curHist;
>         
>         SET @NEW_TOTAL = (@V1 + @V2 + @V3) * @NEW_TOTAL;
>     END
>     
>     SET @FIRST = 0;
>     FETCH NEXT FROM curHist INTO @V1, @V2, @V3, @T;
> END
>
> CLOSE curHist;
> DEALLOCATE curHist;
>
> SELECT * FROM Hist;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> UniqueIdentifierCode | EffectiveDate       | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Total     
> :------------------- | :------------------ | :----- | :----- | :----- | :---------
> N01                  | 12/11/2015 00:00:00 | 2.0000 | 2.0000 | 3.0000 | 20.0000   
> N02                  | 14/11/2015 00:00:00 | 2.0000 | 3.0000 | 1.0000 | 140.0000  
> N03                  | 15/11/2015 00:00:00 | 1.0000 | 1.0000 | 1.0000 | 840.0000  
> N04                  | 17/11/2015 00:00:00 | 1.0000 | 3.0000 | 1.0000 | 2520.0000 
> N05                  | 19/11/2015 00:00:00 | 2.0000 | 1.0000 | 3.0000 | 12600.0000
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ad643726c2b4dec24f21da2c77f14326)*